# Plotting on a BaseMap - unexpected result

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am running the following code, which should be basic basemap stuff:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#basic stuff from the examples
plt.close('all')
m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-80,urcrnrlat=80,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,lat_ts=20,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,91.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,60.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

lon=[
 -44.897539694478894,
 -79.56264363246461,
 -108.31264586027467,
 -129.5832433799378,
 -149.11755440233293,
 173.04624586158417,
 57.26114485166647,
 26.06650557322952,
 6.8910540489469785,
 -15.059586144625898]

lat=[
 -23.30021206811055,
 -22.174848810053106,
 -6.169632450760373,
 18.199421172044598,
 45.95724594253466,
 72.89364342463014,
 69.39230460744983,
 41.88542137864501,
 14.50656439517308,
 -8.974170076274387]

m.plot(lon,lat,latlon=True,c='orange')
m.plot(lon[0:5],lat[0:5],latlon=True,c='green')
m.plot(lon[5:-1],lat[5:-1],latlon=True,c='blue')

plt.show()
```

As you can see, I am drawing a basic map, then plotting stuff on it by latitude and longitude. A whole set of points is drawn in orange, then subsets of those same points are drawn in green and blue. Hence I would expect the orange plot to coincide essentially with the blue and green ones. Instead, here is what I get:[image: sample output]

From what I understand, the correct plot is the blue and green one. The same things does not happen with different choices of points. It seems like `plot()` get confused when the line to plot wraps around the map border in some sense.

**Am I doing something wrong, or is this a `basemap` bug?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting. An example with further illustration of the problem:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-80,urcrnrlat=80,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,lat_ts=20,resolution='l')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,91.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,60.))

lon=[
 -44.897539694478894,
 -79.56264363246461,
 -108.31264586027467,
 -129.5832433799378,
 -149.11755440233293,
 173.04624586158417,
 57.26114485166647,
 26.06650557322952,
 6.8910540489469785,
 -15.059586144625898]

lat=[
 -23.30021206811055,
 -22.174848810053106,
 -6.169632450760373,
 18.199421172044598,
 45.95724594253466,
 72.89364342463014,
 69.39230460744983,
 41.88542137864501,
 14.50656439517308,
 -8.974170076274387]

m.plot(lon, lat, 'ro', markersize=14, mec='none', latlon=True)
m.plot(lon[:-1], lat[:-1], 'bo', markersize=10, mec='none', latlon=True)
m.plot(lon[1:], lat[1:], 'go', markersize=6, mec='none', latlon=True)
```

The data is the same, but just omitting a sample from some point will offset the points:

[image]

The red, green and blue graphs should coincide. It looks really odd but it seems as if the X and Y coordinates were offset with respect to each other in some of the series.

Even the red points do not seem to be where they should be. Either this is a bug or there is something odd in the documentation. (I have `matplotlib` 1.3.1 and `basemap` 1.0.6.)

However, the projection conversion itself seems to work flawlessly:

```
c = m(lon, lat)
cp = m(lon[:-1], lat[:-1])

plt.plot(c[0], c[1], 'kx')
plt.plot(cp[0], cp[1], 'o', mfc='none', mec='k')
```

This creates:

[image]

Now the points are in the correct place (rings and crosses), and the selection of points to draw does not change the position of the points.

It can be seen that the X coordinates (latitudes) are correct in all pictures, but for some reason the longitudes seem almost random. Strange. (Anyway, the workaround is above.)

---

**Update:** I think I found the bug. The `plot` method of `Basemap` first shifts the data so that it starts from the edge of the plot. For example:

```
In [27]: m.shiftdata(lon)
Out[27]: 
array([ 173.04624586,   57.26114485,   26.06650557,    6.89105405,
        -15.05958614,  -44.89753969,  -79.56264363, -108.31264586,
       -129.58324338, -149.1175544 ])
```

This is quite ok, as now lines will be contiguous. Unfortunately, the latitude data is not shifted, and the results are exactly what is shown above.

If you shift both latitudes and longitudes by:

```
lons, lats = m.shiftdata(lon, lat)
```

and use the shifted version to plot the data, everything is fine.

To my eye it seems that there is some hassle with the decorator `_transform1d` used around `plot` and `scatter` methods. Monkey-patching this (`__init.py__`, lines 3239 and 3277 in today's git) by changing the decorator into `_transform` should help, but it may break other functionality in `plot` and `scatter`.

I think the best solution is to sort the data before plotting by using `shiftdata` as above. (And of course to file a bug report.)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent analysis. I ended up doing the conversion manually, too. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: For reference, here is the [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3404).

Comment: I have copied the section with the explanation to the issue, please leave a note over there if you have any other comments.